# Is it possible to show if git branches have the same commits if the one of the branches has been rebased so they don't have the same SHA1 IDs?

Tags: git

I'm trying to get the same effect of running `git branch --merged` but allow for the same commits (commit message + diff) that have been rebased at some point.

Comment: You mean exact same on-disk content despite different commit messages? You could check the tree hashes are the same for the commits, or `git ls-tree` to see which files and folders are the same and which aren't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `git log` with the `--cherry-mark` option will work. Specifically, you can see a set of commits that are the same between a branch `A` and a branch `B` with the following:

```
git log --cherry-mark --oneline --graph --decorate A...B
```

Example output:

```
$ git log --cherry-mark --oneline --graph --decorate master...feature
= 1e4f971 (HEAD, feature) Add some greetings
= 926857a Add some greetings
= bfede5b Add some greetings
= 14099b6 (master) Add some Hellos
= a0576fa Add some Hellos
= 8822553 Add some Hellos
```

In the above output, you will see that the first 3 commits in the output for `feature` are equivalent to the first 3 commits in the output for `master`, though the sha IDs and commit messages are different.

From the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for `git log`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html):

> ```
> --cherry-mark
> ```
>
> Like `--cherry-pick` (see below) but mark equivalent commits with `=` rather than omitting them, and inequivalent ones with `+`.
>
> ```
> --cherry-pick
> ```
>
> Omit any commit that introduces the same change as another commit on the "other side" when the set of commits are limited with symmetric difference.
>
> For example, if you have two branches, A and B, a usual way to list all commits on only one side of them is with `--left-right` (see the example below in the description of the `--left-right` option). It however shows the commits that were cherry-picked from the other branch (for example, "3rd on b" may be cherry-picked from branch A). With this option, such pairs of commits are excluded from the output.

You can also learn more about the triple dot `...` commit range syntax at the [Revision Selection chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges) of the [***FREE*** online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book).